# Rails on Heroku database migration does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I´ve seen a few questions with similar issues but none of them have solved my problem. This is my commands for adding new columns to my db:

```
$ rails g migration "WhateverIWantTodo"
```

I write the code

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

I check on my localhost that everything works with the new fields.

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --app myappname
```

I get no indication that something failed after this, this is the output:

> ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.5ms)  SELECT
>   "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

```
$ heroku restart --app myappname
```

After this I check my live app, get the "Something went wrong" and this is my logs:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name_of_my_new_column'

I´ve tried restart a few times but nothing helps, any ideas?

EDIT: Yes, i did push my code changes to Heroku as well.

This is my migration file:

```
class AddSecondBuyerToClient < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :clients, :second_buyer_email, :string
    add_column :clients, :second_buyer_phone, :string
    add_column :clients, :second_buyer_name, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you push your new code to heroku?

Comment: Yes, added the code with the migration file and the changes that breaks the page.

Comment: Display your migration file

Comment: run `heroku pg:psql` to open postgres on heroku and see if your column is there.  If it is then your error lies in your code, if not I would repush your code and make sure the migration file is getting to heroku.

Comment: do you have the latest code...and pushed it as well ?

Comment: @ChrisBarthol My new columns does not exist and repushing my code now generates an build error, so I guess the error could be there.

Comment: Publish your build error...

Comment: @Gearnode Build log was empty, no error. I did however find my (stupid) issue, see the answer below. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You have all gem for push rails project to heroku ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:Somehow the code push was not complete before I did the migration to Heroku. Seems like the output:

> ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.5ms) SELECT
>   "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

was an indication that **something was wrong** because apparently the output should display your changes.

So lesson of the day: **Make sure that the migration file is pushed to Heroku before running the migration**